# How to get Google Earth images using the Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth

Using Google Earth Engine, I'm attempting to save historical Google Earth images. But I can't seem to find it in either "ee.Image" or "ee.ImageCollection". However, there is Landsat, Sentinel, etc. data available. Can anyone tell me how I can get high-resolution Google Earth images using the Google Earth Engine?

Comment: Sadly, there are a few datasets without global coverage: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/tags/highres

Comment: Thank you, @aldo_tapia, for sharing this useful link and your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but historical Google Earth images are not publicly available. There is some imagery in Earth Engine that is higher resolution than Sentinel2. You might want to take a look at these datasets to start:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/tags/skysat?hl=en

You may want to save out your results from Earth Engine and then load them into Google Earth. If so, this may help - https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting#exporting-maps

Comment: To add a bit more background, the imagery available for free in Earth Engine is generally publicly available data provided by governments for science and research purposes, and the vast majority of that is lower spatial resolution (but higher temporal resolution) than what you usually see in the satellite layers in Google Earth & Maps.
On the other hand, most of the high-resolution imagery visible in Google Earth and Maps is from commercial satellite providers, and purchased under a license allows it to be displayed in Google mapping tools, but not to be re-distributed in original form.

Comment: Thank you @steveGreenberg for detailed answer. It is helpful for me.

Comment: Thank you @C.A. for useful and detail information.